# Unable to fix the logic of the bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a table (say UserInputDetails) with the following entries:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+                                               
| screenId   | userInput | numInput |
+------------+-----------+----------+                                            
| 13_1_2_1   | 2         |        9 |                           
| 13_1_2_2   | 2         |        9 |                       
| 13_1_2_2   | 3         |        2 |                       
| 13_1_2_2   | 9         |        2 |                 
| 13_1_2_2_2 | 3         |        3 |          
| 13_1_2_2_2 | 5         |        2 |   
| 13_2_2_2   | 4         |        4 |          
| 13_2_2_2   | 5         |        4 |         
| 13_2_2_2   | 7         |        2 |         
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I need to write a shell script which gives its expected output as:

```
13_1_2_1,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
13_1_2_2,0,0,9,2,0,0,0,0,0,2
13_1_2_2_2,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,0,0,0
13_2_2_2,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,2,0,0
```

Explanation for the output:

the first line of input denotes the numInputs for a particular userInput for screenId '13_1_2_1'. The line first prints the screenId and then corresponding NumInput for userInput 0-9. Since the numInput for userInput '2' is 9 and for the rest of 0-9 is 0, it gives the value 13_1_2_1,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

The bash script written for the following function is:

```
 #!/bin/bash 

 MYSQL="mysql -uroot -proot -N Database1"

 yesterday=""


 if [ $# -ge 1 ]
 then
     yesterday="$1"
 else
     yesterday=`$MYSQL -sBe "select date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 day);"`
 fi
 echo "DATE: $yesterday"

 PREVSCREENID=''
 SCREENID=
 ABC=tempSqlDataFile
 $MYSQL -sBe "select screenId, userInput, numInput from userInputDetails group by screenID, userInput" > $ABC

 for i in {0..9} 
 do
    arr[$i]='0'
 done

 while read line
 do

     SCREENID=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`
     i=`echo $line | awk '{print $2 }'`
     arr[$i]=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
     if [[ $SCREENID != $PREVSCREENID ]]
     then
         echo "$SCREENID ${arr[*]}" | tr ' ' ','
         for i in {0..9}
         do
             arr[$i]='0'
         done
     else
         i=`echo $line | awk '{print $2 + 1}'`
         arr[$i]=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
     fi
     PREVSCREENID=$SCREENID
 done < $ABC
```

The logic somewhere is going wrong and I am unable to get the logic right. the output from the above shell script is:

```
13_1_2_1,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
13_1_2_2,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
13_1_2_2_2,0,0,9,3,0,0,0,0,0,2,
13_2_2_2,0,0,0,3,4,2,0,0,0,0,
```

Please can you help me fix the logic in my script? Also, since I am new to scripting and programming, this may not be an efficient way to perform this task. Please suggest if there is an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your script. Here's a rewrite of the latter part:

```
while read SCREENID i n; do
    if [[ "$SCREENID" != "$PREVSCREENID" ]]; then
        [ "$PREVSCREENID" ] && echo "$PREVSCREENID ${arr[*]}" | tr ' ' ,
        for j in {0..9}; do arr[$j]=0; done
    fi
    arr[$i]="$n"
    PREVSCREENID="$SCREENID"
done < "$ABC"
echo "$PREVSCREENID ${arr[*]}" | tr ' ' ,
```

You can avoid calling `tr` like this:

```
print_arr() { IFS=,; echo $PREVSCREENID,"${arr[*]}"; unset IFS; }

while read SCREENID i n; do
    if [[ "$SCREENID" != "$PREVSCREENID" ]]; then
        [ "$PREVSCREENID" ] && print_arr
        for j in {0..9}; do arr[$j]=0; done
    fi
    arr[$i]="$n"
    PREVSCREENID="$SCREENID"
done < "$ABC"
print_arr
```